# Angular formBuilder

Tags: angular, formbuilder

I been struggling with the same issue here. I am trying to validate a form using angular formBuilder. Here is my code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.formBuilder = new FormBuilder();
  this.simpleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  notifyMeRadio: [],
  notifyMeEmail: [this.notifyMeEmail,[CommonValidators.isValidEmailAddress]],
  notifyMeSMS: [this.notifyMeSMS, [Validators.minLength(10)]],
  notifyMeFax: [this.notifyMeFax,[CommonValidators.isValidBeneficiaryName]],
  notifyBeneficiaryRadio: [''],
  notifyBeneficiaryEmail: [this.notifyBeneficiaryEmail,[CommonValidators.isValidEmailAddress]],
  notifyBeneficiarySMS: [this.notifyBeneficiarySMS,[Validators.minLength(10)]],
  notifyBeneficiaryFax: [this.notifyBeneficiaryFax,[Validators.minLength(10)]],
  });
  this.simpleForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));
  this.onValueChanged();
}
```

And my validation messages object goes like this:

```
validationMessages = {
  'notifyMeSMS': {'required':'field cannot be empty',
  'isValidEmailAddress':'10 digist'
},
  'notifyMeEmail': {'required': 'Please enter valid Email address'},
  'notifyMeFax' : { 'required': 'Please enter valid Fax name',
  'isValidBeneficiaryName':'isValidBeneficiaryName'
},

  'notifyBeneficiarySMS':  {'required':'Please enter valid SMS', 'isValidEmailAddress':'please type a valid email address'},
  'notifyBeneficiaryEmail': {'required':'required field'},
  'notifyBeneficiaryFax' : {'required':'Please enter valid beneficiary Fax'},
};
```

Form errors here:

```
formErrors: {
  'notifyMeRadio':'',
  'notifyMeEmail': '',
  'notifyMeSMS': '',
  'notifyMeFax': ''
},
```

And finally my OnvalueChange method:

```
onValueChanged(data?: any) {
  if (!this.simpleForm) { return; }
    const form = this.simpleForm;

  for (const field in this.formStatus.formErrors) {

    //this.formStatus.formErrors[this.formStatus.formErrors.notifyMeSMS] = ''
    this.formStatus.formErrors[field] = '';
    const control = form.get(field)
    if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
      const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
      for (const key in control.errors) {
        this.formStatus.formErrors[field] +=messages[key] + ' ' 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My issue here is I can only get validation messages when I include required and it only return required only.

Comment: Could you, please, add some appropriate indents to your code parts?
Actually, the question is not clear, maybe you should revise your post

Comment: Thanks guys for your time..I however managed to resolve my problem. The issue here was ,I set my validation  this.parentFormGroup.controls[this.previousOption.inputID].setValidators(null);